# Tensor Gaussian Integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

I wish to compute the most general tensor Gaussian integral of the form

$$\int [\mathcal{D}A] \exp(-A^{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots \mu_s}M_{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_s\nu_1\nu_2\cdots\nu_s}A^{\nu_1\nu_2\cdots \nu_s})$$

My guess is that the answer should be $$\det(M)^{-1/2}$$ where $\det{M}$ is defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213130/determinant-of-a-tensor) but I am unable to prove it. Can anybody provide a rigorous way to do such an integral?

Comment: In the correct basis this should become a product of single variable gaussian integrals.

Comment: Is $A$ just a tensor, or is it a tensor *field*? In other words, is this just a matrix (tensor) integral or is it actually a path integral? In the former case, I would say that neither of the tags quantum-field-theory or path-integral is appropriate and that the question would be more suitable for math.SE. In the latter case, can you rewrite the action in a more transparent way?

Comment: Hint: raise the manifold dimension to the power of $s$.

Comment: Take *s* =2 first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just rename indices, $\mu_1\mu_2\cdots \mu_s\to i$ (that is, $11\cdots 11\to 1, \ 11\cdots12\to2$, etc, $nn\cdots nn\to n^s$. Then your integral is
$$
\int e^{-A_i M_{ij} A_j}=\underset{ij}{\det}(M_{ij})^{-1/2}
$$

This is also
$$
\underset{ij}{\det}(M_{ij})\epsilon_{j_1\cdots j_N}=\epsilon^{i_1\cdots i_N}M_{i_1j_1}M_{i_2,j_2}\cdots M_{i_N,j_N}
$$
which you can "unfold" into your vector indices, $i_k\to \mu_{1,k}\mu_{2,k}\cdots\mu_{s,k}$, if you so desire.

[This is how computers deal with higher-dimensional arrays, after all.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Address_calculation_in_general)

Comment: Are you trying to say $M_{ij}$ is now an $n^s \times n^s$ matrix and the gaussian integral is now the determinant of this matrix? And what do you mean by unfold?

Comment: Also, is your answer same as my guess or not?

Comment: @user44690 1) Yes. 2) unfold = undo the renaming. 3) It is not clear to me what "your guess" is. The formulas in your linked answer do not make much sense to me. My naive interpretation of what they mean does not seem to be equivalent to what I wrote, though.